# Discord webhook with embed

Tags: python, command, embed, discord.py

I made a few commands for my discord bot. When I Send the command .y or .j6 for the 2nd time it pushes the first one with the second. How can I fix this?

(I need to post more details but i dont have them so i write this so i can post this so dont read this because this is trash)

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed

async def on_ready():
    print('Bot is ready.')

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '.')
webhook_urls = ['https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/694265463936647289/zwRbi6A_jHp9r7kbTwOlWir9rS3-cXtMa6XLHHmrzwgyJtQaLPiisbSQBRgq7v39F6MG', 'https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/699705671440138291/52awf2UE2TgVhumFQKp8ZOo-lz4iBtjt786NC1W1TDElAKCx4spXLP3RNi7O4avuQpHo']
webhook = DiscordWebhook(url=webhook_urls)


@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms')

@client.command()
async def raffle(ctx, link, store, sneaker, raffletype ):
    channel = client.get_channel(642837709198721034)
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=sneaker,
        description=store,
        url=link,
        colour=discord.Colour.blue()

    )
    embed.add_field(name="Release type", value=raffletype)

    embed.set_footer(text='The Hypesply | Chip#4600')

    await channel.send(embed=embed)

@client.command()
@commands.has_role('Owner')
async def j6(ctx, link, store, raffletype ):
    embed = DiscordEmbed(
        title="Nike AirJordan 6 'DMP'",
        url=link,
        colour=discord.Colour.blue()
    )
    embed.add_embed_field(name="Store", value=store)
    embed.add_embed_field(name="Release type", value=raffletype)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://static.sneakerjagers.com/products/660x660/126329.jpg")
    embed.set_footer(text='The Hypesply | Chip#4600')
    webhook.add_embed(embed)
    webhook.execute()

@client.command()
@commands.has_role('Owner')
async def y(ctx, link, store, raffletype):
    embed = DiscordEmbed(
            title="Adidas Yeezyboost 350 V2 'Linen'",
            url=link,
            colour=discord.Colour.blue()
        )
    embed.add_embed_field(name="Store", value=store)
    embed.add_embed_field(name="Release type", value=raffletype)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://static.sneakerjagers.com/products/660x660/155433.jpg")
    embed.set_footer(text='The Hypesply | Chip#4600')
    webhook.add_embed(embed)
    webhook.execute()```
````

Comment: The documentation seems to indicate you should create a new `DiscordWebhook` for each message.

Comment: I should be possible without creating new webhooks though

Comment: Not a new webhook, a new `DiscordWebhook` object